# How to optimise the receive data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am reading data from Serial, can it be more optimise ab2str converter?

```
var lineBuffer = "";
var ab2str = function(buf) {
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bufView);
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(encodedString));
};

function(receiveInfo) {
    var ch = ab2str(receiveInfo.data);
    ch = ch.toString('utf8');
    switch (ch) {
      case "\u0002":
        console.log('>>> STARTED');
        break;      
      case "\u0003":            
        console.log(lineBuffer, lineBuffer.length);
        qrcode = lineBuffer;
        lineBuffer = "";
        console.log('>>> ENDED');
        break;
      default:
        //console.log('>>> ADDING in TROLL: ' , ab2str(receiveInfo.data));
        lineBuffer += ab2str(receiveInfo.data);
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: what is `function(receiveInfo)` ? as far as I can tell it should be throwing an unexpected token exception, shouldn't it? is it working or are you just looking for an optimization?

Comment: https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding

Comment: YES - its working serial.onReceive.addListener(function(receiveInfo) { } but i  want to optimize it more.